# does skewness and correlation impact clustering in k-means algorithm?

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

does skewness and correlation impact clustering in k-means algorithm? I found that the silhouette score fell as i included a numerical column with >1.5 skewness.
I dropped the highly correlated column but the silhouette score did not improve. Is there is a way to improve silhouette score when data has skewed property?